# Getting the children of an element and the the parent of the child :)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Okay guys. What i'm trying to do is create an unordered list (ul) with nested (ul)'s inside of it. I'm trying to modify the classes within the elements of the main (ul)'s and i have no idea how to do this. Let me give you an example. Let's say i have this:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
<li><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">subitem1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">subitem2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Main Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Main Item 4</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">subitem3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">subitem4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

What i'm trying to do is find the nested (ul)'s in the "mainNav" and apply with jquery a class to them. Further more, i need to apply a class and other attributes to the parent (li)'s of the nested (ul)'s. I hope this makes sense. The output would look something like this:

```
<ul id="mainNav">
<li><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" DATA="BLAH">Main Item 2</a> <!-- STUFF GOES HERE -->
   <ul class="dropdown-submenu"> <!-- and here -->
    <li><a href="#">subitem1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">subitem2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Main Item 3</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" DATA="BLAH">>Main Item 4</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
    <li><a href="#">subitem3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">subitem4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm trying to traverse the child elements and add classes to the child elements (ul)'s and then go to the parent element (li) and add classes to that and the (a) elements as well. I'm completely lost and if you guys could help, i would greatly appreciate it!!! Thanks all!!!

Comment: See the edit to my answer to include the a tag.

Comment: I've edited the answer again to correctly add the attribute to the a element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fairly straightforward to do with a single jQuery line:

`$('#mainNav ul').addClass('dropdown-submenu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown');`

Note that using the css selectors, we're just finding any `ul` elements of the mainNav, then adding a class, then we chain another function to find it's parent, and add a class off dropdown.

**EDIT :**
To add the data attribute to the a tag per the example in the question, chain in the `find('a:first').attr('data', 'BLAH')` bit like so:

```
$('#mainNav ul').addClass('dropdown-submenu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown').find('a:first').attr("data", "BLAH");
```

**EDIT 2 :**
To address the next level of ul children, and presumably NOT have all child ul's have the same class, you can use the following script:

```
$('#mainNav > li > ul').addClass('dropdown-menu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown').find('a:first').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown').addClass('dropdown-toggle');  
$('#mainNav ul ul').addClass('dropdown-child-menu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown-child');`
```

Note the change in selector for the first line: this ensures we only get the `ul`'s that are direct descendants of the top-level `li` elements.

The second line selector tells it to get all third level+ `ul` elements (it will get all third, fourth, etc. level `ul` elements).

Comment: what about to the (a) tag within the parent (li) of the nested (ul) tag?

Comment: wow... can't wait to give that a try. i'll probably try it out tomorrow. On another note, how would i handle another tier within the 2nd (ul). so for instance:

`<ul>
  `<li><a href="#">Level1</a>
    `<ul>
      `<li><a href="#">level2</a>
        `<ul>
        `   <li><a href="#">level3</a></li>
        ` </ul>
        `  </li>
       `  </ul>
      `  </li>
     `</ul>

??

Comment: Okay, finally tried the code and it doesn't work. I broke it down into different configurations and i was able to get this working:
`$('#mainNav ul').addClass('dropdown-menu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown');

but i wasn't able to get anything with the anchor tag working. I also was trying to add classes to the anchor tags as well but it wasn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely works.  Tested.  Can you point me at your site where this is running to look at?

Comment: here's the fiddle i made: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/w4Exu/ . If you inspect the results, you'll see that only the nested (ul) has the class added to it. everything else is untouched.

Comment: Dude... that's awesome!!! it worked out great! here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/w4Exu/3/. How would i address manipulating the class on another nested (ul) within the nested (ul)? Thanks again, you are so awesome!

Comment: I tried doing:

$('#mainNav ul').addClass('dropdown-menu').parent('li').addClass('dropdown').find('a:first').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown').addClass('dropdown-toggle').find('ul').addClass('hello');

It doesn't work. I also did (ul:first) but nothing. Thanks man

Comment: @Damien - do you have the html code for the additional nested levels? Are you just interested in a class on those?

Comment: @Damien - answer has been edited to give you the additional nested levels.

Comment: You are Amazing! Wow man, this is so awesome! Just for arguments sake, is there anyway to get that all on one line? I'm not complaining at all, just really facinated. What i was planning on doing was waaaaayyy more complicated than this. I thought i was gonna have write some sort of crazy script to traverse everything and looping and head explosions! Anyway, thanks for all your help. I didn't know that this could be done this way and i learned a lot!

Comment: Sure, there's a way.  But for readability and other reasons, I broke it out into two lines.  This way it's a bit more clear what's going on.  If we chained another selector/function onto the end, it would become quite convoluted.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I have another question related to this one. I'm going to open a new question that way you get credit for it. I would like you to look at it if you can. here's the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371897/jquery-wont-insert-after-my-unordered-list